# LXC starts up, but the networking is not set up - what is preventing this?

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, lxc, dnsmasq

On Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty, I had LXC running, but recently I upgraded from 1.0.7 to 1.1.2 as per the instructions [here on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-lxc/+archive/ubuntu/stable). However, I found that I could not start my containers any more. After stepping through the container startup logs (starting the container with logging output) I could see that it was because the network bridge hadn't been created on startup by `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lxc/lxc-net`, the network startup script for LXC.

I managed to get the bridge up by following [LXC NET fails to create bridge on Ubuntu Server 14.04 | community.flockport.com](https://community.flockport.com/topic/25/lxc-net-fails-to-create-bridge-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-1/2)

However, that still indicated a problem with dnsmasq (no DNS resolution) and lxcbr0 (the default LXC container bridge) not having any NAT rules. The instructions are more of a quick fix to alleviate the symptoms without fixing the problem. I can't ping out of the containers, and it seems to me that the network setup script isn't being run at startup. What can I check next?

Answer (score 2):

The problem, after all that, was that the lxc-net startup script (`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lxc/lxc-net`) expects to not find the file `/var/lock/subsys/lxc-net`. It wasn't being removed for some reason. By doing `rm /var/lock/subsys/lxc-net`, the file was removed and lxc-net startup script ran as expected, creating the network as expected for LXC.

I hope that helps someone in a similar situation.